# java.util.NoSuchElementException:null(in java.util.StringTokenizer)

Tags: java

I am trying to read data from a Serialized file but it gives me an error

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException:null(in java.util.StringTokenizer)
```

Could you please assist me?

```
import java.io.*; 
import java.util.*;
public class SerialFile {

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {


        String  name=" ";
        int  studNumber=0;
        int loanAmount=0;
        String degree=" ";


        try
        {
            ObjectOutputStream out=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("student.ser"));  

            out.writeObject("Jon Smith#123456#12000");
            out.writeObject("Mary Jones#023456#10000#BSc");
            out.writeObject("Sam Snead#654321#15000");
            out.writeObject("Tommy Adams#723456#10000#BCom");  
            out.close();

            ObjectInputStream in=new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("student.ser"));

            while(true)
            {
                String  stud=(String)in.readObject();
                StringTokenizer token=new StringTokenizer(stud,"#");

                name=token.nextToken();
                studNumber=Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
                loanAmount=Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
                degree=token.nextToken();

                System.out.println(name+studNumber+loanAmount+degree);
            }


        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception: "+ioe.getMessage());
        }

        catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception: "+cnfe.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Use `hasMoreTokens()` before `nextToken()`.. (see also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(token.hasMoreTokens())
    degree=token.nextToken();
```

Jon Smith#123456#12000 doesnt has degree. So exception occurred . Please check `hasMoreTokens()` before getting degree

Comment: say for example all the records had a degree but maybe not a student number. The records are in the same format, would I use the same approach?

Comment: I just tried it now and got an errorj
       out.writeObject("Jon Smith#12000#BCom");
        out.writeObject("Mary Jones#023456#10000#BSc");
        out.writeObject("Sam Snead#15000#BCom");
        out.writeObject("Tommy Adams#723456#10000#BCom");     name=token.nextToken();
          if(token.hasMoreTokens())
          studNumber=Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
          if(token.hasMoreTokens())
          loanAmount=Integer.parseInt(token.nextToken());
          if(token.hasMoreTokens())
          degree=token.nextToken();

Comment: Try to keep all records in same format. If doesnt have the value just put default value.